# Excel - Finding Cells with Top Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, rank

```
       | Company 1 | Company 2
Item 1 |     7     |    0
Item 2 |     1     |    0
Item 3 |     2     |    8
Item 4 |     0     |    3
Item 5 |     0     |    1
```

So I need to grab the cell/row number for the top 3 ordered values in a given column so for Company 1 you'd get B2, B4, B3 and for Company 2 you'd get C4, C5, C6.

Comment: Why? are you going to use this information later to return the item list?  If so we can skip a step with an INDEX formula.  Or is the end output desired?

Comment: Basically to make a report on another sheet... I need the Item Name and Value for that report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return the row number use this formula:

```
=MATCH(LARGE(B$2:B$6,ROW(1:1)),B:B,0)
```

[image]

Comment: @Ralph as per my comment to the OP, I asked what was wanted and they did not clarify that they want any values returned, so I went by the `So I need to grab the cell/row number`. If the OP wants more I will let them ask.